# zlib: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back

Tags: python, zlib, deflate, cab

I'm trying to write code to write/read MS-ZIP compressed CAB files. MS-ZIP is using the same deflate algorithm implemented in zlib. I've simplified the problem to this simple script which only involves zlib.

- I know the compress function is correct because other CAB extracting tools can read files produce this way.
- Decompress function is not working. It fails when more than 1 chunk have to be decompressed.

I cannot get the decompression code that matches the compression code right.

```
import sys, struct, zlib

MAX_CHUNK_SIZE = 100

def main():
    uncomp = (b'GQOLELNFJH@?AQE@LBA=?@N@<GJHE=EGE<FQOAM@?<IABT>EK'
              b'<=QFRPBSRGFRENSJLDFGD=LSRHIAO?FB@NP?DGDS>NGT@CCFPS'
              b'A@B=IGG<?JQBGBPLOPONU?IBBSNBK<QAFLGK@>H=CQ?BS><@UE'
              b'QGAKHML@>?JOSEQRCTP>S<?N>DNM@??ARJ>QUJSHLQN<P<>D==')

    print("python", sys.version)
    print("zlib version", zlib.ZLIB_VERSION)
    print("zlib runtime version", zlib.ZLIB_RUNTIME_VERSION)

    chunks = compress(uncomp)
    decomp = decompress(chunks)
    assert(uncomp == decomp)


def compress(data):
    start_off = 0
    data_size = len(data)
    remaining = data_size
    res = []
    zdict = b''

    while start_off < data_size:
        print("compress chunk %d"%len(res))

        chunk_size = min(MAX_CHUNK_SIZE, remaining)
        chunk = data[start_off:start_off+chunk_size]
        c = b''

        z = zlib.compressobj(wbits=-15, zdict=zdict)
        c += z.compress(chunk)
        c += z.flush(zlib.Z_FINISH)

        res.append(c)

        zdict = chunk
        start_off += chunk_size
        remaining -= chunk_size

    return res

def decompress(chunks):
    zdict = b''
    res = []

    for i, c in enumerate(chunks):
        print("decompress chunk %d"%i)
        out = b''

        z = zlib.decompressobj(wbits=-15, zdict=zdict)
        out += z.decompress(c)
        out += z.flush()
        zdict = out

        res.append(out)

    return b''.join(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this script I get:

```
python 3.4.5 (default, Jul 03 2016, 13:55:08) [GCC]
zlib version 1.2.8
zlib runtime version 1.2.8
compress chunk 0
compress chunk 1
decompress chunk 0
decompress chunk 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bug.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File "bug.py", line 16, in main
    decomp = decompress(chunks)
  File "bug.py", line 55, in decompress
    out += z.decompress(c)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back
```

It also fails on ideone.com http://ideone.com/baD3gg which is running python 3.4.3+ zlib 1.2.8

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code, ran it, and got `RESULTS 12/12 OK`.

Comment: (wow, hi Mark!!) I consistently get these errors (tests 5,6,7,8,9,10,11 sometime 2, 3). Running zlib 1.2.8. 

I've tried to dump the data and decompress it with a C program, same results than the python script (also linking against 1.2.8) will edit my post with more code.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: Had to add an `import struct`, but still consistently get `RESULTS 12/12 OK`.

Comment: Also after fixing a small bug in your C code, changing `dict_size = chunk_size;` to `dict_size = z.total_out;`, the C decompression of the dumped "raw" files works fine as well.

Comment: Indeed, the C code works for me after that fix but the python script still doesn't. I've updated my question with a even more simple script (smaller chunk size and sample input provided) that fails here. Could it be a bug in the python wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I was running into CPython issue #27164. As I'm writing this (2016-11-21), a fix is available in branches master and 3.5 only.

https://bugs.python.org/issue27164

Comment: Indeed the version of python I have is 3.5.2. I got: `python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
zlib version 1.2.3
zlib runtime version 1.2.8
compress chunk 0
compress chunk 1
decompress chunk 0
decompress chunk 1`